# Delivering large artwork at 50% size for printer

Tags: print-design

I apologise in advance for a very noob question!

I'm working on a piece of artwork to be printed at 4 Sheet size. The printer will accept the artwork at 50% (or smaller) since it's a big print.

My question - to deliver the art at 50% - I'm assuming that means the overall area of the artwork I supply should be 50% of the intended print size? Presumably if I sent them artwork with width and height each set at half the intended print size, that would count as sending it to them at 25%?

Possibly a very stupid question, but I thought I'd just check!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding scale for printers, don't worry about calculating area. 50% applies to dimensions. So a 70 x 40 print at 50% would just be 35 x 20. Always verify with your print provider, but this is pretty much a universal practice.

Answer (score 0):

Note: It's best to ask your printer to specify what they have in mind. There are no stupid questions and it's better to ask at the begginign then go back and fourth with final file.

That aside - when a printed state 50% (or 25% or 10%) of original I would undesrtand that the physical dimensions should be set to that amount.
So if final print is 2x4 my file should have 1x2 (metres, inches, foots, DLs). 
**WHILE** at the same the resolution should be upscaled by two. So if the print resolution is 100 DPI (or ppI or PPI or hoofs) then that reduced file should be 200.

Now, to specify your question. Is the 4 sheet print your requirment or is it printing process? Like for example 1 billboard is made from 6 sheets. If the splicing is done due to printing requirment then you should resize the final, whole, picture.
If the splicing is done through your requirment (like for example collages with Print on Canvas) then IMHO each sheet (frame) should be resized on it's own.

Side note - it won't be counted as 25%. It would still be the 50% of overall picture. The diference lies only in alghoritms that re-calculate the pixels, colors etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I don't have direct access to the printers - it's more that the client has passed me on their standard requirements for printing; but I guess I could ask them to ask whoever they are using etc.

Comment: The '4 Sheet' as far as I'm aware a standard print size in the UK - 1016mm x 1524mm. I assume it'll be printed on 4 sheets, but I'm only giving them one artwork file. Given that if I reduce those dimensions by 50% I get a "1 Sheet" size - 508mm x 762mm, then the resultant area is 25% - ie 4 "1 sheets" arranged together make up a "4 Sheet" - which is what was confusing me. But if generally 50% is taken to mean reducing all dimensions by 50%, that that's great, that's what I need to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leave it the same size, but 50% of the resolution (for print you should work with 300 pixel/inch resolution, if they ask for 50% that means work with 150ppi)

Comment: If the OP was to work at 50% at 150ppi - when enlarged the res would be lower. Often the resolution can be lower for larger prints at 100% because the viewer will be seeing the art at a greater distance (poster / banner or large outdoor ad) so the detail is not as important. 300 ppi is recommended when viewing magazine, flyer or similar 'close-up' medium.